# Does Batman's utility belt have any other "standard" equipment besides grapple guns, ropes, communicators, gas pellets, bombs and batarangs?

Tags: dc, batman

I was trying to find specifically what "base gear" a utility belt would have. In several comics, and even films, it's shown/stated that Batman tends to choose his gear based around specific threats or mission parameters, or what he expects he might encounter. For instance, he doesn't have enough Kryptonite to fit into *all* of his belts, but makes sure to  equip and carry it should he be dealing with Superman or other Kryptonians.

So I was just curious as to the "basic gear" most belts would have. From comics and various media observation, as well as the **Batman encyclopedia,** for most missions, this would include:

- Batarangs/Bat-shurikens
- Grappling gun and hooks
- Smoke and gas pellets
- Mini bombs/explosives/explosive gel
- Cutting tools
- Flashlight
- Communications gear
- Tracers
- Remote to vehicles
- Binoculars/Vision gear
- Hand cuffs
- Silk ropes or cord

I'm uncertain if there is anything else he *always* carries into battle, though.

Is there any canon source which makes this plain?

**Note:** I'm willing to take answers that take into account the different "Eras" Batman worked in, because the technology of the time *would* inform his gear. However, for simplicity, we should probably stick to the modern era [Post-Crisis] versions, and try to be as broad as possible.

Also, this would be most specific to examples of *weapons,* as most of the gear mentioned above is used for something other than "direct" combat.

Also, looking at different media interpretations, from comics to video games, is fine; it can help us build a somewhat "general" list.

Comment: You forgot shark repellent

Comment: @Valorum - That would be handy with recent Harley Quinn encounters.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%27s_utility_belt), the buckle *'typically contains a miniature camera and a tape recorder.'* Most literature on the utility belt also mentions one form or another of locking or defense gizmos to prevent tampering.

Comment: You might have to be a little more era specific. The grapple-gun with attached bat-rope wasn't introduced until Tim Burton's Batman. Before that, he just hooked some bat-rope to a bat-a-rang and threw that. The advances in available and imaginary bat-technologies has come a long way from Batman's introduction to present day and there are bound to be items that were once standard that got grandfathered out.

Comment: @Valorum No no, I was aware of that. That was a weapon kept specifically in the bat _boat,_  or sometimes copter, not on the belt. He would only _place it_ in if he knew he was going to be near water.

Comment: @Jeeped Hmmm, I don't know; I saw him use a grappling hook like gun in some of the older  _Super Powers Team_ episodes, but you are right that it became more "Standard" after the Burton movie. I'll edit the question to suit. Thanks, friend.

Answer (score 7):

Whatever Bat-gadget is considered "never leave home without it" varies by depiction (comic series, TV show, movie series, etc). Sometimes changes to the standard arsenal are part of the setting: futuristic versions of Bat-gadgets and the Batsuit in *Batman Beyond* are intended to set it apart from *Batman: The Animated Series*. Your list does cover many staples common to several depictions.

Even within each depiction it's not easily apparent what those gadgets are because Batman does not take out every one in a single sitting. People have attempted to catalog gadgets of the utility belt in wikis for Batman TV shows or movies, though you will have to watch the source material to make your own opinion of which gadget is standard besides the staples like the batarangs and grapple gun. Assuming that a gadget that shows up several times for no obvious plot reason is one that is brought into battle regularly, one particularly bizarre gadget not yet mentioned is a belt sword in the animated TV series *Batman: the Brave and the Bold*.
[image: Batman's not-a-light-saber]

It's worth pointing out the various diagrams you can find will not necessarily follow the source material, whether by adding gadgets to fill up space or omitting gadgets because they aren't visible on the belt. Here's one based on the belt depicted in the *Dark Knight* film trilogy, and there are several gadgets never used on-screen while the oft-used spherical bombs are nowhere to be seen (and depicted in *Batman Begins* to be too thick to be stored in the pouches or cylinders).
[image: Dark Knight Trilogy Belt]

Comment: I would assume that Batman is picking gadgets based on which baddies are known to be at large in Gotham. There's little point carrying around laughing  gas antidote if the Joker is in Arkham

Comment: Yeah, Batman is still primarily a stealthy hand-to-hand combatant, so besides the batarangs, grapple gun, and maybe smoke bombs, most of Batman's standard arsenal in any modern depiction will take a backseat to the gadgets Batman prepares for specific scenarios. Every rogue Superman story will have several closeups of Batman's kryptonite stash, but the lockpicks may just have a single panel or a couple seconds of a sound effect.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Thanks, man. But this is _why_ I asked this question. See, if Batman's thinking is utilitarian, then he _probably_ used a basis of thinking similar to that of Shinobi, who had 8 essential tools they _always_ brought with them (An _Amigasa_ hat, a hook & rope, a slate pencil, a flint stone, a 3 foot towel, first aid medicine, a small blade for cutting, and a type of lock pick). A short staff was also often used. Working as spies, these would be more common than the claws, egg shell bombs, cultraps, throwing knives, chains and swords we typically see them depicted with for combat.

Comment: I have a very faint memory, from DC comics in the mid 1960's, of Robin getting a rusty nail in the palm of his hand. The Caped Crusader instantly whipped out a penicillin shot from his belt - to prevent infection - (note that there was no mention of an anti-tetanus jab!)